# Why does Python ignore comment indentation?

Tags: python, comments, whitespace, indentation

Apparently, this:

```
def f():
    pass
# maybe the function is over
    pass  # oh wait, it's not

f()
```

is valid syntax, whereas this is not:

```
def f():
    pass
''' maybe the function is over '''
    pass  # oh wait, it's not

f()
```

That comes as a huge surprise to me. So my questions are:

- Why? Why does Python not consider the first version to be a syntax error?
- Is there anything in PEP8 recommending that this not be done?

Comment: why would it be a syntax error? comments by nature are being ignored by the interpreter. Why would they affect actual code?

Comment: It's not even consistent - I'll edit the question

Comment: Comments by nature are ignored by the interpreter after the _beginning_ of the comment; that's obvious. What's not obvious is why the beginning of the comment does not matter.

Comment: The reason for that is becasue the triple quotes `'''` serve a special meaning - they start a docstring. So in that case they should generally be in-line with the current scope. Try for example to remove the first `pass` and see how that changes the error

Comment: And BTW, from [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#block-comments): *Block comments generally apply to some (or all) code that follows them, and are indented to the same level as that code.*

Comment: So PEP8 makes that explicit for block comments, but the inverse is not made explicit for single-line comments.

Comment: I think there is nothing explicitly saying there that a block comment can't be one line. It is **block** comment as opposed to **inline** comment. Not **multiline** comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the first one is valid because it starts with `#` which defined in the language to be a comment line so it's ignored and its indentation won't end functions or start new ones.

The latter is different, it's a string evaluated but its value is never used, you could use that to achieve multi line comments but still the interpreter will try to evaluate that string as code, so the indentation of this string matter to the interpreter and it could end scopes.

for the second one writing something like

```
'''comment''''
```

is as much code to the interpreter as this

```
my_var = '''comment'''
```

But this

```
# comment
```

is ignored and is not code to the interpreter.